# What is an innermost "if" statement and an enclosing "if"?

Tags: gcc

First, please allow me to post a screenshot of the man page of GCC.

[image]

The sentence just above the second bundle of demo code confuses me, which is written as "so there is no way the 'else' could belong to the enclosing 'if'." As far as I try to get the idea of the author, the innermost if statement is `if(b)` and `foo();`. He intended to refer to if(b) when he said the "enclosing 'if'". But if my guess is right, the demo code should be like this:

```
    {
       if(a)
          {
             if(b)
                foo();
          }
       else
          bar();
    }
```

Am I right? The question turns out to be what an "enclosing 'if' " is.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/innermost - if(b). enclosing is the other one: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enclosing - if(a).

Comment: Why is my question migrated here? It says "migrated from unix.stackexchange.com 11 mins ago".

Comment: It was off-topic there.

Comment: @user43312 Programming is [on topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on unix.stackexchange.com only if it concerns shell scripting or API / system interfaces. Other programming questions are on topic here.

Comment: @Tim, OK, first time to be here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "enclosing if" is the `if` in whose body another ("inner") if is "enclosed".

The sentence that confuses you is correct. The paragraph states, that you should put the parenthesis as shown in the second example to achieve the same result as in the first example (but without a warning from `gcc`).

If you want to have code as it is suggested by the indentation of example 1, your example would be correct.

Now what the sentence means is: In example 1 the `else` clause belongs to the inner `if`, but this could only be by accident (when the behaviour in your example is desired).
When you write the code as it is in example 2, "there is no way" that you could have intended this.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I try to get the idea of the author, the innermost if statement is if(b) and foo();

Yes. And the `else` is a clause of it, not a clause of the enclosing if.

> He intended to refer to if(b) when he said the "enclosing 'if'".

No.  S/he was discussing a means of making it clear that the `else` belongs to the innermost if and not the enclosing one.  Clear to the compiler, that is, so that it won't throw this warning.

Beyond that, the two examples are functionally identical.  The only difference is that one will provoke a warning. Your version with braces is functionally different than those two -- it makes the `else` a clause of the enclosing `if(a)`.

Comment: @glodilocks. Thanks. I payed attention to `This is often not what the programmer expected` and thus coded as the programmer's expectation. I hope I am resonable.